# PostGIS update geo column with ST_GeogFromText and get lon/lat from another column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I started to use PostGIS recently and i have a table with a column **longitudes** and a column **latitudes**.
I want to know if it's possible (and how) to put these lon/lat columns informations into the new geographical column (with possibly ST_GeogFromText)

I already tried something like :

```
UPDATE my_table SET geo = ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4267;POINT(lon.my_table lat.my_table)');
```

Thanks for your reading and you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_GeogFromText takes a formatted text of EWKT, which is a lossy and inefficient method.

Try using ST_MakePoint instead:

```
UPDATE my_table SET geo = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4267)::geography;
```